# Using "rails runner" for cron jobs is very CPU intensive - alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently using cron and "rails runner" to execute background jobs.  For the most part these jobs are simple polls "Find the records that are due to receive a reminder email. Send that email."

I've been watching my Amazon EC2 Small instance, and noticed that each time one of these cron job kicks in, the CPU spikes to ~99%.  The teeny tiny little query inside my current job is definitely *not* responsible.  I'm presuming that the spike is simply due to the effort of loading the full rails environment via "rails runner".

Is there a more CPU efficient way to handle regularly scheduled batch jobs?

P.S.  I know that in the particular example of sending a reminder email at time X in the future, I could delayed_jobs, and simply schedule the job in the future.  Not every possible task fits into the delayed_jobs framework very well though, so I'm looking for a more traditional "cron job" type solution.  Like "rails runner", but without the crazy CPU consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use workers witch don't load rails env. Or load it only once(like [resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque))

Comment: Thanks! Resque looks more like an alternative to Delayed Jobs though, then an alternative to "rails runner".  E.g., like Delayed Jobs it seems to satisfy the "do this job once at time X" rather then "do this job at a regular interval".

Comment: You can create interval running jobs too  with loop and sleep. I use loop. And resque gives me "resque-web" for monitoring workers

Comment: Great, thanks!  I also just found the "resque-scheduler" which might be just the thing I need. https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution for this, since you do need to load a Rails environment to handle whatever that is you are handling. So when on the "cron" model you will be starting up a handler which in turn will create some load on your instance. I don't know how cloud services lend themselves to this, but I think the optimal model in your case would be to have a running daemon for job handling and forking coupled with REE for the job execution (that helps prevent memory leaks by letting as much as possible happen in the child process that will die at the end of the execution loop).

The daemon could be configured to accept signals (also via a job queue) that would spin off jobs doing specific things.

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose I could create an administrative "page" in my application that would run the code in the jobs.  The cron job could then just request that page via wget.  The advantage would be that the job would then execute in the already living Apache/Passenger Rails environment.